# add_rewrite_rule with bottom priority doesn't handle the Wordpress pages

Tags: php, functions, permalinks, pages, rewrite-rules

I have a php file named `test.php` that outputs the `page` querystring parameter.

I want to use `add_rewrite_rule` to serve my php file, while the WordPress pages which exist already or will be created should have priority: for example, if I catch `bar`, `baz` and `foo-*` in my regex, and then I add a page named `baz` (living under the `/baz` url) and another one named `/foo-bar`, both should be served from the database (by WordPress), not by my php file.

This is my custom rewrite in `functions.php`:

```
function custom_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^(bar|baz|foo-.*)', 'test.php?page=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite');
```

This works fine: it catches `bar`, `baz`, `foo-*` urls. But when I create a page named `bar` it still uses my `test.php` to serve the content.

I tried to use `bottom` instead of `top` as the third argument in the `add_rewrite_rule` call, but it does not make any change.

After each edit in `functions.php` I made sure to click the <kbd>Save changes</kbd> button in *Permalink Settings*.

How can I fix this?

I want something like this:

> ```
> Client ---- [does the WP page exist?] --- YES -> Serve it from DB
>                         \----- NO -- [is the url matched by my regex?]
>                                          |            |
>                                         YES           NO
>                                          |            |
>                                          v            |
>                                       test.php        404
> ```

Obviously, if there are other rules, check them first and then show 404.

Comment: you have an external rule, it's always going to win over internal rules. you have to point rules to index.php to get an internal rule.

Comment: @Milo How can I do that? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you point a rule to anything other than `index.php`, it gets interpreted as external and written to the .htaccess file. After external rules are parsed, requests get directed to WordPress, which parses the internal rules in php. This is the internal version:

```
function custom_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^(bar|baz|foo-.*)',
    'index.php?my_var=$matches[1]',
    'top'
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite' );
```

You'll also need to register the custom query var you use in the rule. Note that `page` is already in use by WordPress

```
function wpd_query_vars( $qvars ) {
  $qvars[] = 'my_var';
  return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_query_vars' , 10, 1 );
```

This alone won't do much, you'll have to check if a page that matches your rule exists, and load your file if it doesn't. We can do that on the `parse_request` action.

```
function wpd_parse_request( $request ) {
    // if the rule was matched, the query var will be set
    if( isset( $request->query_vars['my_var'] ) ){
        // check if a page exists, reset query vars to load that page if it does
        if( get_page_by_path( $request->query_vars['my_var'] ) ){
            $request->query_vars['pagename'] = $request->query_vars['my_var'];
            unset( $request->query_vars['my_var'] );
        // else load the file
        } else {
            include 'test.php';
            die();
        }
    }
    return $request;
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_parse_request' );
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for the nice answer! It worked. You have a missing semicolon on the `include 'test.php'` line.

Comment: Can you improve this to handle posts as well? For example, if there is a post that exists on that url, render it.